# Rails 4 showing blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting blank page for my main `root` route

```
root 'payslips#index'
```

Below is the code I have for that controller

```
class PayslipsController < ApplicationController
  require 'CSV'

  def index
    @income_tax_rates = IncomeTaxRates.all
  end
end
```

The controller has been generated by `rails g controller payslips` command

I'm still getting blank page.

I've also checked log file (`development.log`) but nothing in there but a valid `get` like below:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-30 10:01:52 +1000
```

What could have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Model names are singular, not plural. So try:

```
@income_tax_rates = IncomeTaxRate.all
```

Comment: Nope. Same issue. I've also tried commenting that line out. View is showing a normal HTML

Comment: Can you check in your model what exactly is the name of your class?

Comment: The name of it is now IncomeTaxRate

Comment: Also try `require 'csv'` without capitals.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Restart your app?

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: `<h1>Payslips#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/payslips/index.html.erb</p>`

Comment: I got it. I had a reserved word `process` as a function name in the same controller! This is a wake up call for us to be careful of those names when working with Rails!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us code for your view? When ever i build my application i always delete index.html file form public folder and then setup my root

```
root :to => 'controller_name#action_name'
```

In your views are you using `<%= %>` rather than `<% %>`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, got a blank page with the content of a javascript function every time I tried to access a particular route.


I was deploying to a subdirectory using config.assets.prefix and config.url_prefix. Turned out that there were assets with exactly the same address as my route so instead of going to the 
corresponding controller the server was replying with the content of the .js asset.


You could see the source code of another page to check if the assets direction is overlapping with some of your routes